# Global shared variable

Tags: python

In my project, I would like to have a global "Filemanager", so that I always access up-to-date information. I have written a nice short example to explain my problem since I don't want to paste my entire code here.

I have two files: 
main.py

```py
class GlobalList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = []

    def add(self, toadd):
        self.pool.append(toadd)

global list
list = GlobalList()
list.add("Test from main")

from other_file import add_sth
add_sth()

list.add("Hello again from main.py")
```

other_file.py

```py
def addme():
    global list
    list.add("Hello from other_file.py")
```

This does NOT work since the addme function cannot access the global "list" variable. 
I also tried "importing" the list from the main module using

```py
from main import list

def addme():
    list.add("Hello from other_file.py")
```

Which to no surprise doesn't work because it throws a circular import error.

I really don't want to pass the "list" object to every function requiring it because then every function would have a lot of parameters.

Comment: I suggest that you revise your rule that: `I really don't want to pass the "file" object`.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. What specifically does your code do that it shouldn't, or not do that it should? What is your expected vs. actual result? Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can easily break that recursive import by putting the GlobalList in a different file from main.py.

#### global_list.py

```py
class GlobalList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = []

    def add(self, toadd):
        self.pool.append(toadd)

glist = GlobalList()
```

#### other_file.py

```py
from global_list import glist

def add_sth():
    glist.add("Hello from other_file.py")
```

#### main.py

```py
from global_list import glist
glist.add("Test from main")

from other_file import add_sth
add_sth()

glist.add("Hello again from main.py")

print(glist.pool)
```

#### Which outputs

```
['Test from main', 'Hello from other_file.py', 'Hello again from main.py']
```

Answer (score 0):

Much as I want you to pass `GlobalList` around, to solve your exact problem at the moment you should put this code:

```py
class GlobalList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.pool = []

    def add(self, toadd):
        self.pool.append(toadd)

global_list = GlobalList()
```

into, say, `Global.py`

Then *all* your other files should start with:

`from Global import global_list`

and access it like: `global_list.add("Test from main")`